# Android to PC/ PC to android bluetooth/wifi live audio stream

Tags: c#, android, audio, bluetooth, stream

I've searched for this for some time, but I can't find anything about my problem. What I would like to do is to connect an android phone to PC via bluetooth or wifi (already done using sockets) and use the PC's headset (with microphone) to talk on the phone. 
I've found some examples/tutorials on how to stream music but I would need live audio from the microphone and it should be full duplex. 
Is this possible?
Any comments are appreciated

Comment: Have you tried Tapi?

Comment: I want to build this app, as I saw Tapi is a product that can be downloaded from store :)

Comment: it's an interface ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to accomplish this in the bluetooth settings for the device (in this case, the device is your PC)

On your android phone, you go to your bluetooth settings, select settings icon next to the the paired device (probably the PC name), and then select with the check boxes what activities you want to use the device for. All available activities such as phone calls and media will and keyboard will show up here. If it does not show up, then it must not be a supported bluetooth capability either on your phone or the PC. [image]

Comment: Yes, It could be a solution, but what I want to do, (and I don't know how) is to send the data in full duplex mode from my app on the phone to my app on the PC and vice-versa :)